# Problemas para recargar mi servidor local de Angular

Tags: angular

Creé mi proyecto de angular con `ng serve` que el cual al yo salir de éste y apretar el botón de arriba a la izquierda para refrescar me aparece la siguiente pantalla de error diciendo:

> No se puede acceder a este sitio web"

Y se queda así para siempre:

[image: captura del mensaje de error]

Ya miré mi antivirus y no tengo al navegador bloqueado. Instalé de nuevo el CLI de Angular y creé otro proyecto y sigue igual.

Y como podrán ver yo entro con el enlace de mis páginas favoritas y también ya probé poniendo el enlace de `localhost`, pero la página tiene la misma pantalla de error.

*Información de utilidad:*

Terminal CMD de Windows:

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\dist\AngularNuevo\proyectoWeb>ng serve
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size
vendor.js             | vendor        |   1.77 MB |
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 318.06 kB |
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 210.09 kB |
main.js               | main          |  48.05 kB |
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.52 kB |

                      | Initial Total |   2.34 MB

Build at: 2022-09-21T11:30:05.077Z - Hash: cc6d0b4e24614b82 - Time: 19417ms

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


√ Compiled successfully.
```

Luego de eso mando la carpeta a VS Code el cual me pregunta si confío en el creador de este archivo, respondo que sí;.

Una vez colocada esta carpeta de `AngularNuevo` en mi VS Code
ingreso esto `<h1>{{title}}</h1>` en: `app.component.html`.

[image: captura de pantalla de VS Code]

Después voy a `localhost` insertando el siguiente enlace en la barra de direcciones: `http://localhost:4200/`

[image: captura del enlace]

Y hasta ahí todo bien: mi `<h1>{{title}}</h1>` se ejecutó bien, le doy a recargar la página, la recarga sin problema.

Luego salgo, vuelvo a entrar de la misma forma que antes (insertando el siguiente enlace en la barra de direcciones: `http://localhost:4200/`).

Coloco más códigos `<h1>{{1 + 1}}</h1>  <h1>{{1 + 7}}</h1>`, cierro la terminal, reinicio la página y me sale el error.

---

Escribiendo esto me doy cuenta que el error en la pagina me sale al cerrar la terminal.
Supongo que la terminal mantiene encendido mi `ng serve` y al cerrar la este se apaga.

Comment: Qué te sale en el log cuando le das `ng serve`? Ve a [edit] y lo incluyes en la pregunta

Comment: No veo ni la terminal, ni VS Code, ni algún IDE/Editor de código, Cuando ejecutas el comando `ng serve` ¿en dónde lo haces? y ¿qué haces con el programa donde aplicaste dicho comando?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: No recuerdo que me salía cuando coloque el ng serve pero puedo crear otro proyecto (que seguro va a a dar el mismo error) y mandarles que es lo que dice la terminal

Comment: Y diganme si es seguro mandar el link del repositorio de git hub por stack overflow así les este proyecto. Y si no es seguro puedo copiar y pegar el código de las carpetas de Angular (si es que le sirve de algo para solucionar el problema).

Comment: Mañana por la mañana edito la pregunta y mando toda la información  que me piden

Comment: Por la captura de pantalla que proporcionas, no veo la ventana del terminal donde ejecutas `ng serve`. Recuerda que esa instrucción genera un servidor web de desarrollo que, en caso de pararlo, deja de servir las páginas web. Para generar una página estática que pueda ser cargada por un servidor web estándar (apache, nginx, etc) debes usar [`ng build`](https://angular.io/cli/build). ¿Qué servidor web tienes instalado en tu máquina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la captura de pantalla que proporcionas y posteriormente al leer tu respuesta, veo que cierras la ventana del terminal donde ejecutas `ng serve`.

Esa instrucción genera un servidor web de desarrollo que, en caso de pararlo, deja de servir las páginas web.

Para generar una página estática que pueda ser cargada por un servidor web estándar (apache, nginx, etc) debes usar [`ng build`](https://angular.io/cli/build).

Puedes generar el sitio web directamente en la raíz del servidor web, o bien generar la web en el directorio del proyecto y posteriormente copiar los archivos al directorio raíz del servidor web o bien enviarlo por FTP/SFTP/SCP al servidor remoto que alojará tus páginas web.

---

### Ejemplos:

Para generar la página web en un subdirectorio llamado `dist` dentro del proyecto de trabajo para posteriormente subirlo a un servidor web externo, o bien copiar/pegar al destino:

```
ng build
```

Ejemplo generando el sitio web en el directorio raíz de una instalación WAMP típica:

```
ng build --output-path C:\Apache2\htdocs
```

Ejemplo para un servidor XAMPP:

```
ng build --output-path C:\xampp\htdocs
```